# What is the difference between var bar = require('myModule') and only require('myModule')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have seen that in some projects it is used the common

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
```

but in some other cases it is used something like :

```
require('myModule');
```

what's the difference between those two ?

Comment: What is the diff. between `var some = someFn();` and `someFn();`?

Comment: Depends where it is declared.

Comment: I still don't get it, I mean... I know the difference between var some = someFn(); and someFn(); but I don't see it in the require mode.

Answer (score 1):

One assigns the module to a variable, the other only requires it. Both load and run the script.

With `require('foo')`, you require the module and load the entry point script. This will evaluate any static code in that script when the module loads for the first time. You do not get access to any exports and cannot reference the module later without requiring it again.

The `var bar = require('foo')` behaves similarly, except it keeps a reference to the exports and allows you to use them later.

The require-without-assign form is often seen when the "module" is actually some other type of resource, such as a CSS file, and `require` runs some code to load that CSS into the current page. In common JS modules, without any initialization code, the require-without-assign form will pre-load a module but do little else.

Take a module like:

```
let connection = new ServerConnection();

export default class Connection {
  static getConnection() {
    return connection;
  }
}
```

The require-without-assign form will load the script, run it, and create the connection. You won't be able to use it, but it will exist.

The require-with-assign form will load, run, create, and provide a reference. You will be able to call `bar.getConnection()` and get access to the connection.

In the above example, if you use `require` without assign, you won't have access to the connection and will never be able to close it, which could be a problem.